# PHPmailer sending email with Attachment

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a script for sending emails with PHPmailer (the class is different because I use a CRUD but the functions are the same)

This is the script:

```
    if (array_key_exists('recipient', $_POST)) {
        $attachment = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachment']['name']));
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $attachment);
        $recipient = $_POST['recipient']; 
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        //$attachment = $_POST['attachment'];

        $email->Sender = "noreply@fw.net";
        $email->Recipient = "noreply@fw.net";
        if (!empty($_POST['recipient'])) {
            $email->Recipient = $recipient;
        } else { 
            foreach ($bcc as $bcc) {
                $email->addBcc($bcc);
        }
    }   
    //$email->addRecipient = $bcc;
    $email->Subject = $subject;
    $email->Content = $content; 
    $email->addAttachment($attachment, 'MyFile');
    $email->Format = "html";
    //$email->send();

    if(!$email->send()) {
        $msg = '<div style="Color:red">Sent:</div>'. $email->SendErrDescription;    
    } else {
        $msg = '<div style="Color:green">not Sent</div>';
        header("Refresh:5");
    }
}
```

this the form: email.php (work on the same page script / form)

```
<form id="mess" action="email.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php if ($Page->CheckToken) { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo TOKEN_NAME ?>" value="<?php echo $Page->Token ?>">
<?php } ?>
<div id="jsInfo" data-count="<?php echo $count; ?>"></div>
<div class="card card-primary card-outline">
.......
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> Allegato
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"> <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment">
                  </div>
                  <p class="help-block">Max. 10MB</p>
                </div>
........
                  <button type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Send </button>
```

I changed the destination to php.ini I use wamp in local for testing
from:

```
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```

to

```
sys_temp_dir = "c:/Users/lt/Documents/Temp"
```

Question:

Why is not attached to the original file(pdf,jpg,bmp,txt ecc..), but the *.tmp file is attached. ? where am I wrong?

let's say I solved that.

```
don't works
$attachment = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachment']['name']));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $attachment);

works
$uploaddir = 'C:/wamp64/www/fw3/';
$attachment_tmp = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$attachment_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($attachment_tmp, $uploaddir . $attachment_name);
```

I have two problems again ...
1) How to send the attachment to all recipients?
2) When sending a 4Mb file the page loads a lot of time, how can I modify the script to make the sending work in the background?

Comment: Hi, I am not getting what the problem is here?

Comment: PHP delivers the uploaded file into the tmp folder with its own generated name i.e. a filename like `43fCBE6.tmp` This is done BEFORE you get control. PHP should then delete that temp file when this script finishes

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $attachment); RETURN-> false

Comment: The script is moving uploaded files to an uploads directory – see the call to `move_uploaded_file` – and that's the correct, safe way of doing that. Uploads have two names - the original filename the user provided, and the internal temporary name. The main thing to bear in mind that is that user-supplied filenames should not be trusted - validate and filter them before use.

Comment: if `move_uploaded_file()` returns false then [look at the reasons for that in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: I am not really sure why you are moving the file anywhere, you can attach the file that is given to you by PHP from the folder it places it in, and let PHP look after removing it from the temp dir when the script completes